# MySQL query to reorder field values?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

```
===============
| rank | name |
===============
|    3 | john |
|    6 |  bob |
|   10 | alex |
|   11 | brad |
|   12 | matt |
|   34 | luke |
|  145 |  ben |
===============
```

(this table is an example. In reality my table consists of ~5000 rows of data).

Is there a query to reorder the rank values starting from 1 and going up so it ends up like this:

```
===============
| rank | name |
===============
|    1 | john |
|    2 |  bob |
|    3 | alex |
|    4 | brad |
|    5 | matt |
|    6 | luke |
|    7 |  ben |
===============
```

It would be preferable to do this in 1 or 2 queries, not 1 query for each row since my table has 5000+ rows.

**EDIT**: Sorry I wasn't clear. I am trying to UPDATE the values in the database.

Comment: WHY do you care how the entries are physically ordered in the DB? The view (including order) should be controlled at the display layer (in SQL's case: in the resultset of a query).

Comment: #1 it's out of my control. If my client asks for something, I do it (if it's possible). #2, in some cases, the rank # can be duplicated (multiple rows with the same rank), which can really mess up stuff on the frontend of the application. So reordering their values starting from 1 is important.

Comment: Actually, [duplicate ranks can be handled by the query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855462/detect-future-duplicate-values-while-iterating-through-mysql-results-in-php) from the front-end application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with for this problem:

1.Create a temporary table without any keys

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;
```

2.Populate the temporary table with data from the original table, ordered by rank

```
INSERT INTO tempTable SELECT id FROM myTable ORDER BY rank;
```

3.Add auto-incrementing rank column, giving all rows a unique rank, counting up from 1

```
ALTER TABLE tempTable
    ADD COLUMN `rank` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`rank`);
```

4.Update the original table with a join to the temp table, overriding the original ranks

```
UPDATE myTable 
INNER JOIN tempTable
    ON myTable.id = tempTable.id
SET myTable.rank = tempTable.rank;
```

5.Drop the temp table

```
DROP TABLE tempTable;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a little crude but will work in a pinch.

First order your table correctly just incase

`ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY rank`

Then drop the column

`ALTER TABLE tablename DROP rank`

Then add it again, with auto increment

`ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN rank INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST`

The auto increment will take care of numbering them in order, plus you don't have to loop through each row.

Comment: NEAT!! Can't say anything else :-))

Comment: What exactly does the `ALTER TABLE ORDER BY` do? Does it set the default `ORDER BY` for when using a `SELECT` query?

Comment: This won't work in my case because the table has a `PRIMARY KEY id` field and I am only allowed to have one `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.

Comment: Yes, you may have to "break" the table temporarily to get this to work. Even harder if you have foreign keys (then again they would get messed up anyway).

Comment: I found a solution (posted and accepted) that is similar, involving creating a temporary table, populating it, adding the auto-increment column and then updating the original table with the new values. +1 to you for the auto-incrementing column idea though! The database is used in a high traffic website so breaking the table even momentarily could be a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a strict MySQL solution would be to loop through the rows with a scripting language.  Not a great idea if you have a large table, but could be acceptable if this is a one time fix.

In PHP

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database', $db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT rank
                        FROM myTable
                        ORDER BY rank");

$i = 1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE myTable
                SET rank = " . $i++ . "
                WHERE rank = " . $row['rank']);
}
```

Note that this will only work if `rank` is unique and you traverse in an order.

Comment: Appreciated but as I stated in my original question, my table is about 5000+ rows so running 5000+ queries on the server is something I wanted to avoid. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @a:=(select max(id) from mytable)+1;
update mytable set id=(@a:=@a+1)
order by id;
set @a := 0;
update mytable set id=(@a:=@a+1)
order by id;
```

simple way, work for me. easy way.