# Calculate overall and division ranking via arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ranking

This is a follow-up to [Detect future duplicate values while iterating through MySQL results in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855462/detect-future-duplicate-values-while-iterating-through-mysql-results-in-php).

I have an SQL query which produces the results:

```
team_id   division_id   wins
-------------------------------
10        2             44
9         2             42
5         1             42
2         1             42
3         1             41
11        2             40
1         1             36
8         2             31
7         2             29
12        2             24
4         1             20
6         1             18
```

I'm trying to calculate a given team's **overall** and **divisional rankings**.

For example, **team_id = 1**:

```
Overall:       7
Divisional:    4
```

For **team_id = 3**:

```
Overall:       5
Divisional:    3
```

For **team_id = 9**:

```
Overall:     T-2  //must indicate tie
Divisional:    2
```

As you can see from the linked previous question/answer, I can calculate the Overall rank just fine. The issue comes with calculating the divisional rank as well (including properly handling ties).

I've tried storing the results in a multi-dimensional array like `$arr['wins']['division_id']['team_id']`, such as...

```
44 =>  2 => 10
42 =>  1 =>  5
             2
       2 =>  9
41 =>  1 =>  3
40 => 11 =>  2
...
```

But am stuck as to how to iterate through and get my two respective ranks, *as well as detecting ties appropriately for each*.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// Dataset as defined on question
$arr = array(
array('team_id' => 10, 'division_id' => 2, 'wins' => 44),
array('team_id' => 9, 'division_id' => 2, 'wins' => 42),
array('team_id' => 5, 'division_id' => 1, 'wins' => 42),
array('team_id' => 2, 'division_id' => 1, 'wins' => 42),
array('team_id' => 3, 'division_id' => 1, 'wins' => 41),
array('team_id' => 11, 'division_id' => 2, 'wins' => 40),
array('team_id' => 1, 'division_id' => 1, 'wins' => 36),
array('team_id' => 8, 'division_id' => 2, 'wins' => 31),
array('team_id' => 7, 'division_id' => 2, 'wins' => 29),
array('team_id' => 12, 'division_id' => 2, 'wins' => 24),
array('team_id' => 4, 'division_id' => 1, 'wins' => 20),
array('team_id' => 6, 'division_id' => 1, 'wins' => 18));


$divisionTeam = array();
$divisionWins = array();
foreach($arr as $team) {
    $divisionTeam[$team['division_id']][] = $team['team_id'];
    $divisionWins[$team['division_id']][] = $team['wins'];
}



echo "<pre>";
foreach (array_keys($divisionTeam) as $division_id) {
    $rank = 0;
    $prevWins = -1;
    echo "DIVISION $division_id \n";
    foreach ($divisionTeam[$division_id] as $index => $team_id) {

       if ($prevWins == $divisionWins[$division_id][$index]) {
           echo $team_id . " T - " . $rank . "\n";
       }
       else { 
           $rank++;
           echo $team_id . " " . $rank . "\n";
       }
       $prevWins = $divisionWins[$division_id][$index];

    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but 2 issues: that doesn't give me overall rank across both divisions, and the ties aren't handled correctly (only one tied team has "T-" appended, and the next team's rank isn't incremented appropriately).